# Problems running code with Python IDLE

Tags: python

I have been attempting to work an iCreate, roomba without a vacuum cleaner attached using Python 2.7.1 and have created working code. When I type each line in by hand it works perfectly, however when putting all the code in together it stalls and does not operate.

```
import Create
import VideoCapture
from PIL import Image, Imagechops
import os
robot = Create.Create(3)
camera = VideoCapture.Device(0, 1)
(rgb_red, rgb_green, rgb_blue) = (0, 0, 0)
red = Image.open("Red.jpeg")
(redr, redg, redb) = red.getpixel((0, 0))
blue = Image.open("Blue.jpeg")
(bluer, blueg, blueb) = blue.getpixel((0, 0))
green = Image.open("Green.jpeg")
(greenr, greeng, greenb) = green.getpixel((0, 0))
yellow = Image.open("Yellow.jpeg")
(yellowr, yellowg, yellowb) = yellow.getpixel((0, 0))
camera.getImage(0, 0, 'tl')
camera.saveSnapshot('CurrentPicture.jpeg', 0, 0, 'tl')
pic = Image.open("CurrentPicture.jpeg")
(rgb_red, rgb_green, rgb_blue) = pic.getpixel((0, 0))
os.remove("C:\Python27\CurrentPicture.jpeg")
while 0 == 0:
    if((rgb_red - redr) < (rgb_green - greeng)) and ((rgb_red - redr) < (rgb_blue - blueb)):
        robot.stop()
    elif((rgb_blue - blueb) < (rgb_green - greeng)) and ((rgb_blue - blueb) < (rgb_red - redr)):
        robot.turn(45, 40)
    elif((rgb_green - greeng) < (rgb_red - redr)) and ((rgb_green - greeng) < (rgb_blue - blueb)):
        robot.move(50, 50)
    camera.saveSnapshot('CurrentPicture.jpeg', 0, 0, 'tl')
    pic = Image.open("CurrentPicture.jpeg")
    (rgb_red, rgb_green, rgb_blue) = pic.getpixel((0, 0))
    os.remove("C:\Python27\CurrentPicture.jpeg")
```

Are there any issues with IDLE for running multiple lines and just not working, I am not terribly sure what I should be asking. It is just that nothing happens when I run that entire block together but line by line entering works.

-Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where's the part that does stuff?  This code has no output.

Comment: "when putting all the code in together it stalls and does not operate"?  What does this mean?  Please be very specific on what **exactly** you did.  What did you type?  What command did you run?  What did you see as a response?

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead if pasting the code into IDLE, save it into a file, and run it like this:

   python yourfile.py
2. `while 0 == 0:` You might want `while True:` instead.
3. `red = Image.open("Red.jpeg")
   (redr, redg, redb) = red.getpixel((0, 0))` is a very complex way of saying `RED = (255, 0, 0)`

Comment: The file and True are good ideas and I will try them. The reason I did the long drawn out way is because it isn't actually 255, 0, 0 it is actually a red sheet of cardboard I'm using so it has to compare to those sheets in order to determine the command or at least that is what I am trying to do.                                                             Thanks for the response.

Comment: Ah, I see. But it's still probably better to save those values once, instead of everytime you run the program. :-)